# Ubuntu building Qt 6.1 from source

Tags: gcc, qt

I just moved from Windows to Ubuntu and it's a shame things don't seem to work quite so easily as in Windows. I built Qt from source on Windows and didn't have problems. On Ubuntu building is successful but I get "Qmake Not Executable" when I try to add qmake to Qt Versions.

I tested creating makefiles with qmake and it worked.

file qmake: /home/usr/Qt/6.1.0/build/bin/qmake: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

qmake -v: QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 6.1.0 in /home/usr/Qt/6.1.0/build/lib

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2
- Compiler: gcc-11.1.0

Edit 1

Turns out the problem is GCC-11.1. I was able to build a working qmake with GCC-9.3. Can anyone explain why?

Edit 2

Finally had time to test compiling with Qt today. There is an error message in the Kit: The compiler "Clang++12" (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit) cannot produce code for Qt version "Qt 6.1.0" (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit)

This is bonkers, I built the thing with clang. If I change compilers to gcc then I get an okay from the kit but then I have all kinds of problems compiling.

It would be great if someone could give some guidance on how to resolve these problems.

I hope it's possible to run Qt 6 with the newest compilers on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the question. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ships [Qt 5.12](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/qtbase-opensource-src), which is stable and functional.
So at first I should note that using distro-shipped version of Qt (and Gtk, WxWidgets and so on) is always better.  By doing so you can have some warranty about yours self-developed application portability to the same Ubuntu version. User will only need to install needed Qt-related packages on the system.
Moreover the future of Qt 6.x in Debian and Ubuntu is [not clear](https://perezmeyer.blogspot.com/2020/08/stepping-down-as-qt-6-maintainers.html).

If you really want to proceed with compilation use the solution below. Enable source code *deb-src* repositories manually or by using Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtbase5-dev libxcb
sudo apt-get install cmake ninja-build clang build-essential libb2-dev libzstd-dev \
libsystemd-dev libhunspell-dev libclang-10-dev libmng-dev \
libwebp-dev libdouble-conversion-dev libkrb5-dev libdirectfb-dev libts-dev \
libproxy-dev libsctp-dev libbrotli-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.1/6.1.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.1.0.tar.xz
tar -xf qt-everywhere-src-6.1.0.tar.xz

cd qt-everywhere-src-6.1.0
./configure
cmake --build . --parallel
```

> Once everything is built, Qt is installed. You should NOT run '`cmake --install .`'
> Note that this build cannot be deployed to other machines or devices.
>
> To configure and build other Qt modules, you can use the following convenience script:
>
> ```
> ~/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-6.1.0/qtbase/bin/qt-configure-module
> ```

Comment: I don't think all those packages are necessary. I'm pretty sure all required packages are stated here <https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-requirements.html> I can't be completely certain since I manually uninstalled packages stated above after I got a succesful build.

Comment: I tested building with Clang-12 and it was successful. So Am I to believe that GCC-11.1 is buggy or how to go about resolving this?

Comment: Ouch! It sucks if no one takes the Qt6 ride... I also don't have time, though. Plus that one is like 30 different packages. That's a monster library/tools... and probably a ton of testing to make sure it works. I wonder whether the Qt owners will consider taking over. Maybe some people from the KDE. Oh, well...